# ImageMagick / Bash : pipe ignored(?) when filename format variable used

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I'm trying to create a thumbnail sheet (a grid of thumbnails) using ImageMagick with filenames beneath each image. The filenames are long UUID style strings, and using the -title option they overflow into each other to create an unreadable mess. So I thought I'd truncate the names to only show the first n characters. My Bash script is below (running via Git Bash on Windows 11.) I'm not sure whether this is an error in my Bash code, or my use of ImageMagick.

```
magick montage -verbose -label "$(echo '%t' | cut -c -8)" -font Arial -pointsize 16 \
    -background '#000000' -fill 'gray' \
    -define jpeg:size=200x200 \
    -geometry 200x200+2+2 -tile 8x0 \
    -auto-orient \
    $(ls -rt *.jpg) \
    out.jpg
```

As far as I can tell the issue I have is with the `$(echo '%t'` ... part of the script in the first line; it doesn't seem to be piped into the cut command following it. If I use a literal string, eg. `echo 'Hello world!'`, each thumbnail is labeled with what I'd expect, 'Hello wo'. But if I instead use %t (which is ImageMagick's format variable for exposing the base filename of the image) I get the full untruncated filename as if the cut command isn't being applied.

When I use a naked format variable (I've tried %f, the full filename, and %t, the base filename), without echo'ing it into cut, I get the expected untruncated filename. As mentioned, if I echo a literal string (Hello world!) piped into cut, I get the expected truncated output. It is only when I combine the two to echo %f or %t into cut that the truncation fails and I get the full filename. I've also tried piping the echo into sed instead of cut, but yet again the second command is ignored and I get the full filename.

EDIT: An extra little detail I forgot: if I do something funky with the %t, like `$(echo 'xxx%t')`, I get the filename preceded by xxx -- so it seems the echo is working as expected. But when I try to pipe it into cut, it doesn't truncate.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: `%t` is expanded by `magick` later - it's not a variable in your shell. You ask bash to literally take first 8 chars of string `%t`. which is `%t`, and then feed it to the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not at a proper machine to test this on, but I think it's simpler if you use a two-stage approach. First, generate each of the images with its label, then pipe all those into a second `montage` command to lay them all out together. In simple terms, that will look like this:

```
for f in *.jpg; do
   # Generate a single, labelled image on stdout in MIFF format
   magick "$f" ... MIFF:-
done | magick montage MIFF:- ... result.jpg
```

I use `MIFF` as the intermediate format because it can preserve and propagate any bit-depth, any transparency and all meta-data.

So, your actual command will look more like this:

```
for f in  $(ls -rt *.jpg) ; do
   # Take first 8 characters, no need to invoke external process like "cut"
   label="${f:0:8}"
   magick "$f" -label "$label" -font Arial -pointsize 16 \ 
          -auto-orient -resize 200x200 -background black \
          -fill grey MIFF:-
done | magick montage -background black MIFF:- -geometry +2+2 -tile 8x result.jpg
```

---

Remember not to put any debug code inside the `for` loop that writes on `stdout` because it will get sent to the final `montage` command and confuse it. So, if you want debug statements inside the `for` loop, use `stderr` like this:

```
>&2 echo DEBUG: Processing file $f
```

---

Note that you may want to add `-extent 200x200` to the command inside the `for` loop to ensure smaller, or different aspect-ratio images are padded up to a full 200x200.

---

If, during the debug stage, you want to see the individual images that are getting sent through the pipe, you can write them to the filesystem as well by changing the `magick` command in the `for` loop to write an extra copy:

```
for ... ; do
    magick "$f" ... -write "DEBUG-${label}.jpg" MIFF:-
done | magick montage MIFF:- ...
```